# Error while trying to connect AD using LDAP connection

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Trying to use this code to connect the AD

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain)
```

but i got the error saying:

> The LDAP server is unavailable.

Any idea?

Comment: yep.
I've put the domain name and the container.

Comment: Very strange. When i create new PrincipalContext with no domain name(or null), it works fine.

new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

Comment: It could be something as simple as a DNS configuration problem - try adjusting the DNS config and see if that helps.

Comment: the "domain" is string contains the AD path on the network.
Did i gout you right?

Comment: Maybe port 389 or 636 closed? **Ports: 389 , 636** http://blog.evanmc.com/?p=9

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The questions is: do you specify our domain as

- "mydomain.com" (DNS format)
- or as "dc=mydomain,dc=com" (AD-style format)

To my surprise, the Domain name must be in **DNS format** (e.g. "mydomain.com") in order for this to work (and *NOT* in the usual AD-style format of "dc=mydomain,dc=com").

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Mine was because the webserver was not on the same domain as the user.

I resolved it by ignoring the error; this then forced an authentication challenge which enabled the user to supply credentials, which I could pick up the correct domain from.

Comment: can you share how did you fix it?

Comment: @LoverBugs Really sorry my memory won't go back that far!

Comment: Enjoy, I resolved it :D thank you anyways :))